# Неправильное выставление уровня UAC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uac

Проект на C++ собирается Visual Studio 2015. UAC Execution Level выставлен в asInvoker, но почему-то 32-битная версия приложения требует права администратора, а 64-битная нет. Других манифестов в проекте нет.

Где ещё в проекте может быть выставлена настройка, из-за которой приложение собирается с UAC?

UPD Забыла добавить, что изменение этой настройки(UAC Execution Level) никак не влияет на сборку, 32-битная всё также собирается с требованиями, а 64-битная нет

Comment: Может в 32-битной версии настройки отличаются от 64-битной?

Comment: Нет, по крайней мере я пробовала даже в WinMerge сравнивать, различия есть только в некоторых библиотеках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась выставлением Generate Manifest в Yes и Embeded Manifest в Yes

Но мне осталось непонятным почему без этого 32 битная собирается с UAC, а 64 битная без.